# Autocorrelation in Autokey

Tags: cryptanalysis, classical-cipher, vigenere

I know that Vigenère can broken using auto-correlation ([as explained at cryptool-online.org](http://www.cryptool-online.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=90&Itemid=107&lang=en)). Now my question is: Why does this also work with autokey (tested it using crypttool)?

To prove that I have already put work into this, I have read Simon Singh: “The Code Book”, F.L.Bauer: “Decrypted Secrets”. Though the latter book said in does not work the same way in autokey than it does in Vigenère. Why is there still a maximum of coincidences when the text is shifted by the key length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Vigenère cipher, the $i$-th ciphertext letter $c_i$ is calculated as $p_i + k_{i \bmod \ell}$, where $p_i$ is the $i$-th plaintext letter, $k_i$ is the $i$-th key letter, and $\ell$ is the length of the key.  Thus, the difference between two ciphertext letters at positions $i$ and $j$ is $$c_i - c_j = p_i - p_j + c_{i \bmod \ell} - c_{j \bmod \ell}.$$

Normally, for this difference to be zero, the difference between the key letters would have to just happen to cancel out the difference between the plaintext letters.  When $i \equiv j \pmod \ell$, however, the last two terms cancel out, leaving just $p_i - p_j$, which, since the plaintext typically has an uneven letter frequency distribution, is more likely to be zero than one would otherwise expect.

Now, consider the [autokey cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autokey_cipher), where (beyond the first $\ell$ letters) $c_i = p_i + p_{i-\ell}$.  Now the difference between two ciphertext letters is given by $$c_i - c_j = p_i - p_j + p_{i-\ell} - p_{j-\ell}.$$  This time, when $i - j = \ell$, it's the *middle* terms that cancel, leaving just $p_i - p_{j-\ell}$ $=$ $p_i - p_{i-2\ell}$.

Again, it's a lot more likely for a single pair of plaintext letters to be identical than it is for the differences of two pairs of letters to cancel out just by chance.  Exactly *how* much more likely depends on details of the plaintext frequency distribution, but the qualitative behavior is quite robust and shows up for most naturally occurring letter frequencies.

---

Ps. Note that the conditions for this cancellation to occur are different.  For the Vigenère cipher, cancellation occurs whenever $i - j$ is a multiple of the key length $\ell$, producing a characteristic [comb-shaped autocorrelation plot](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15742/solving-vignere-encryption/15745#15745).  For an autokey cipher, however, cancellation only occurs when $i - j$ exactly equals the key length, resulting in just a single peak.

Answer (score -1):

It works with autokey system because the key itself have a bias : in the key is much more E than other letters (this is a natural consequence of using a clear text as key).

Comment: How does that result in a maximum of correlations when shifting by the length of the key?